# Mongoose query for obtaining all results that contains an array of strings that matches any string in a list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So imagine I have an array inside an object in Mongoose. For example, an account has many aliases:

aliases: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Now, imagine that I want to find all accounts that have either "a" or "c" as one of their aliases.

How would you do this in mongoose/mongodb? I know you can use $regex for finding the account that has one of either "a" or "c", but how do you do this for an arbitrary match list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```
db.accounts.find({aliases: {$in: ["a", "c"]}});
```

Comment: If I do this, then it only works if aliases refer to one name rather than a list of names.

Comment: @user3736336 Oh, so you want the aliases array to contain `"a"` AND `"c"`?

Comment: not a and c, but I want ones that contain either a or c.

Comment: @user3736336 Thats exactly what this query does - 'a' OR 'c'. Check up the documentaiton: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score -1):

I use the c# driver to write linq ,

```
   IMongoQuery mongoQuery = Query<YourEntity>.Where(a => a.Aliases.Contains("a") || a.Aliases.Contains("c"));

        var str1 = mongoQuery.ToString();
```

this is the translate by driver

{ "$or" : [{ "Aliases" : "a" }, { "Aliases" : "c" }] }

Comment: The OP is not using C#, he specifically said Mongoshell or Mongoose

Comment: { "$or" : [{ "Aliases" : "a" }, { "Aliases" : "c" }] } is the bson query

Comment: @David Grinberg c# official drive is offered by 10gen that can allow you to write linq , and the driver can translate linq to bson query . offen , it means the best way to query by bson query  statement.  it can used in mongoVUE and mongoose

Comment: Thats fine and dandy, but the OP is still not asking for a c# solution. Moreover, the `$in` operator is simpler.